# Upload an .nupkg file to my Azure function using Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, nuget, azureportal

I have a .nupkg file on my computer that I need to use in my Azure function.

I'm currently using the Azure portal to create my Azure function and I was wondering how can I install my package using my .nupkg file that I have on my PC.

I have a function.proj that references the file, which looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="<MY PACKAGE NAME>" Version="<VERSION NUM>" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, since the nuget package is not on the website, it says `"No package exits"`

How can I upload my .nupkg file so I can use it in my Azure function using the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement following below steps. Instead of whole .nuspec file I have uploaded the required dlls and .proj file from local machine to Azure portal through your VS code's Cloud Explorer.

[image]

Alternatively, you can drag and drop the dlls through KUDU Console from portal.

[image]

*NOTE : Make sure you also add dependencies to a .proj file.*

Comment: How do you add the dependencies in the .proj file

Comment: @XiongXu You need to create the .proj file locally first and manually add relevant nuget references that you are using in your function and then upload it the same way as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I did that and it doesnt work, I keep getting `No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org`, as mentioned in the OP this package is not in nuget